# Connecting of WSO2 IOT Server to WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to connect WSO2 IOT Server to WSO2 IS Server for user authorization. Is there any way to connect WSO2 IOT Server to WSO2 IS Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IS as a key manager by following the docs https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Identity+Server+5.2.0+as+a+Key+Manager+with+API+Manager+2.0.0

In addition to above there are few IoT related feature that needs to be installed in the IS[1]

[1] https://github.com/wso2/carbon-device-mgt/tree/master/features/oauth-extensions